# why does returning the jquery AJAX promise in this function fail to give me the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, deferred

This AJAX works on jsfiddle

```
var a = $.ajax({
    url: "/echo/json/",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            a: true
        })
    },
    dataType: "json"
});

a.done(function (data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Why won't it work when I make `a` the function and return the AJAX promise?

```
var a = function () {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            json: JSON.stringify({
                a: true
            })
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

a.done(function (data) {

    console.log(data);

});
```

Is this not the correct syntax? Well, apparently not, but how can I build the AJAX request into the function? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/noqyq7rg/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `a` is a function, you have to call it:

```
a().done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```